# PHP Media Manager like WordPress Media Uploader?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, file-upload

I simply love the ease at which Wordpress makes the uploading and the management of the photos and media so effortless.

I wanted to implement something like the WordPress Media Uploader into my NON-WORDPRESS PHP site. The problem is I really havent been able to find a good one till now.

Few of the features that I am looking for :

1. File uploader in it just like WP with the file upload progress.
2. Does not use Flash for uploading. **This is really important.**
3. Drag and Drop as well, maybe?
4. File manager which shows all the files that are uploaded as well.
5. Something possibly free? **( Le me getting greedy now :P )**

I have found out the the media manager uses Plupload for its uploading if I am not mistaken. 
And even the **MoxieManager** seems like a good manager. However, it is not free.

Is there an alternative? Or I would have to make my own from scratch?

Please guide me.

Comment: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php

Comment: [uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com)

Comment: https://github.com/Guley/media-manager

Answer (score 12):

I would say to check out the Responsive Filemanager.

http://responsivefilemanager.com

Comment: I downloaded this demo but not working with me? How can I getting started with it?

Comment: The documentation is found here http://responsivefilemanager.com/#documentation-section Let me know if you have specific questions.

Comment: about step 4-Subscribe to Aviary.com to get a free app key (NB the free account limits the export of images to a maximum of 800x800 pixels) 
---- In Aviary the sign up now not available

Comment: Looks like Aviary isn't taking new signups, I'm not sure if they're comparable but I would look at https://creativesdk.adobe.com and setup a web app to get the API key. However I believe the system will still work without Aviary.

Comment: It looks complicated I did my own based on elfinder as here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814396/how-to-make-image-uploader-like-wordpress/28211532#28211532 thanks a lot

Comment: I still have not found an idea I like... I wonder how hard it would be to separate off the media portion of Wordpress as a stand alone program. Just for file uploading.

Comment: Cool, if it wouldn't come with the edit part. For editing, use FileRobot, it is much more powerful. It wild couple just fine if this tool wouldn't force Aviary (well, you can hide its edit features but that would still include the code for it...